# is vAxis: {slantedText: true} possible for Bar Chart [Google Charts]?

Tags: google-visualization

I am able to make `hAxis: {slantedText: true}` for Column Chart 
but is it also applicable to vAxis for Bar Chart?

**Column Chart:**
[image: column chart with slanted text on hAxis]
**Bar Chart:**
[image: bar chart with default text angle on vAxis]

*(don't mind the data, this is just an example)*

Comment: It is working - you're just looking at the wrong axis (see the numbers on your BarChart).  You need to use `vAxis.slantedText` with the BarCharts.

Comment: If you look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72LAj/) setting `slantedText` doesn't do it for the `vAxis`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72LAj/) setting `vAxis.slantedText: true` won't suffice. I'm not sure why, and to my (limited) knowledge I don't know of any easy way to achieve this.

Depending on your desperation, you can add this crude code to the end of your `drawChart` function to achieve a similar rotation for the vAxis labels ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/795/)):

```
// Rotate vAxis labels.
var array = $('g');
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var logicalname = array[i].logicalname;
    var text = $(array[i].children[0]);    
    if(logicalname != null &&
       logicalname.indexOf("vAxis") == 0 &&
       logicalname.indexOf("label") > 0) {

        text.attr("transform", 
                  "rotate(-30 "+$(text[0]).attr('x')+" "+$(text[0]).attr('y')+")");

    }
}
```

Hopefully someone figures out a smoother way to achieve this.

Comment: but what if I only want to apply it to one specific chart?

Comment: A more specific selector should do. `var array = $('#chart g');`, like [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/797/).